# FATAL: could not write lock file "postmaster.pid": No space left on device

Tags: postgresql, docker, resources, diskspace

I'm running a PostgreSQL database in a docker container. I allocated 300Gb for docker and everything was going great, having like 90% of free space. Some day I got this error, `PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization:: FATAL:  could not write lock file "postmaster.pid": No space left on device`, which I don't know where it came from and how to actually fix it. Temporarily, I just increased the size to 400Gb, which fixed it, but why? Now I have 95% space left, which goes according to the previous output of 90% free space. I tried to trace using `df -h` and some other commands to check for disk usage and didn't find anything. Has anyone faced something similar?

I tried `df -h` to check for disk usage and allocate more docker resources

Comment: you can try ```du -h```

Comment: @samilekesiz that just gives me the size of each folder right? It doesn't provide much more information than df -h

Comment: Knowing which directory has increased can give us a starting point for searching for the problem.

Comment: if you have done batch operation like load test, wal may accumulate in the pg_wal directory. Later, as postgres writes these files to the disk, the disk space can be freed.

Comment: I don't think I understood you :/ sorry. But as I said, I had no directory increasing, I got 90% of free space but I just got that error. I thought was due to old docker images but just pruned them and release 1Gb xD which is nothing since I have 360Gb left

Comment: When did you check with `df -h`?  Maybe the space wasn't being used at the time you checked because it wasn't used yet, or had already been cleaned up.  Did you check inodes as well?

Comment: That's a great point and I checked after the error. But since I had 360Gb left, and we didn't clean logs or anything else, it made me thing that that wasn't the problem. How can i check the inodes?

Comment: figure it out ?

Comment: I believe it was due to RAM problems but I'm not sure about it, as many requests were done at the same time and could trigger the memory usage. If not, some shady docker memory management that I don't have the experience to understand yet. I'm sorry